# Rails 5 - Javscript return undefined value

Tags: javascript, json, ruby

Javascript return "undefined" value after installing Rails 5.

My ruby method:

```
def get_info
        runtime_id = params[:runtime_id]
        type = params[:type]
        if (type == SEQUENCE)
            runtime = Runtime.where(:id => runtime_id).first
            name = runtime.name
            
        elsif (play_type == GROUP)
            runtime = GroupRuntime.where(:id => runtime_id).first
            name = runtime.group_name
        end
        browser_name = runtime.browser_name
        browser_version = runtime.browser_version
        
        info = {'title' => name,
               'browser_name' => browser_name,
               'browser_version' => browser_version
        }

logger.info("------- json #{info}")
        
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json {
                render :json => info.to_json
            }
        end
    end
```

My javascript function:

```
function get_info (runtime_id, type) {
   var json = $.ajax({
        url: 'srs/get_info',
        type: "POST",
        data: {runtime_id: runtime_id, type: type},
        async: false
    });
   return json;
}
```

If check my logs for "info" json from get_runtime_info method I can see that json as expected but when I print out value with console.log, "undefined" value is returned. I'm not sure what to do and why value not rendered correctly.

Log:
------- json {"title"=>"smoke", "browser_name"=>"Mozilla Firefox", "browser_version"=>"Mozilla Firefox 84.0.2"}
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)

Few weeks ago I have upgraded rails 4 to rails 5. On rails 4 everything works fine but with one difference in code:

```
respond_to do |format|
            format.html {
                render :text => info.to_json
            }
```

```
function get_runtime_info (runtime_id, type) {
   var json = JSON.parse($.ajax({
        url: 'srs/get_info',
        type: "POST",
        data: {runtime_id: runtime_id, play_type:play_type},
        async: false
    }).responseText);
   return json;
}
```

If anyone could know the answer please help. Thx!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where did you type `console.log`, and what did you try to log? Is the behavioural change caused by the the rails upgrade, or the other changes in your code? You've changed from `format.json` to `format.html`!

Comment: Ok, I forgot put in post part for console.log.
`var name = get_info(runtime_id, type).title;`
 `console.log(name);`
Behavioural change caused after rails upgrade. After upgrade I had to change from `format.html` to `format.json` because "uncaught ReferenceError" raised in console. I have no errors at the moment but var name = undefined.

Comment: Does using `dataType: "json"` in `$.ajax(...)` help? This should explicitly set the `Accept: application/json` header in the request.

Comment: @DomagojMarosevic You should learn how to debug the problem. Try putting a `binding.pry` (or `byebug`) in the rails controller to see what path the code takes. Try looking in your browser/s network tab to see what the API call actually returned. Try adding a `debugger` in the `get_runtime_info` function to inspect the data in more detail. Your biggest problem here is that you're trying to diagnose a relatively complex system with `console.log` -- which is not a good way to do it. There are better tools/techniques available, and you should learn how to use them.

Comment: Problem solved, missed responseJSON
`var name = get_info(runtime_id, type).responseJSON.title`